# How do Python developers manage Javascript/CSS library dependencies?

Tags: python

Coming from C#, management of -all- dependencies was done using NuGet. In Python, PIP is used to manage python packages. Is there any de facto standard for managing Javascript and CSS library dependencies?

Comment: I dont understand the question ... typically with  <link> <style> and <script> tags?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I'm looking for a tool like PIP, but for CSS/Javascript libraries, so i don't have to manually download, update and add them to my project.

Comment: typically css and js libraries are uncoupled from your project ... css libraries are just a skin that tells the browser how to display your content independent of the content itself

Comment: @JoranBeasly Sorry, what do you mean with that second sentence? I just can't believe, that Python programmers manually download and check updates for 20+ JS/CSS libraries.

Comment: Web development usually doesn't require so many packages. What are you designing, a spacecraft?

Comment: @dante its not just python... in any language that you write web stuff in...

Comment: anytime css/js is required it is typically included in the bigger package (ie django includes some css/js in its pip install) ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I disagree, NuGet (http://www.nuget.org/) manages both .NET dll-s and web libraries.

Comment: @yuvi For what century are you developing for :P? As an example: Angular, Twitter Bootstrap, JQuery, QUnit, Sinon, UnderscoreJs, Toastr, MetroJs. Add a few addons and you've got 20 libraries/frameworks.

Comment: now I see more of what you are looking for ... the python part was confusing ... because it has nothing to do with just python ... its just javascript general package management

Comment: See but those libraries are not like python libraries, and you probably don't want them automatically updated. Bootstrap for example is very different between versions, so it's not just about updating the package. You also need to make sure it doesn't screw up anything you were using. That's why most web developers don't use package managers like how python uses pip. It's just not the same

Comment: @yuvi Then you either update the code or revert the package (css/jss library). I don't understand why you are against automating manual labour. As a Python developer, you don't use PIP? It's not about automatic updates, it's about automating the management of packages.

Comment: I'm not against it, I'm just not seeing the need, and it's fairly easy to build a simple package manager of your own using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well javascript and css are their own languages ... so just use that(NuGet) to manage your js/css ... python jquery is the same as .net jquery ...  if you are just looking for a javascript package manager then JAM works i think http://jamjs.org/ ...

bower.io also seems to be a sort of manager for css/js  ... but the python bit was misleading ... these have nothing to do with python specifically ...

Answer (score 2):

python is the language, I guess you mean some web platform like django. however, there is no javascript / css management tool at part of the platform.

Comment: afaik this holds true for pretty much any platform ... (WRT js/css) (+1 all the same)

Answer (score 0):

In the Python world, [Fanstatic](http://www.fanstatic.org) is probably the most widely used (framework-agnostic) solution for that purpose.